# Getting Id that contains a string using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get all the values contained in some input texts. The Ids of the inputs are something like `something_#index#_value` assuming that #index# is an integer so the first Id is something_1_value.

This is what I've tried so far :

```
$("input[id$='_value'] [id*=i]").each(function (j, el) { // Some actions }
```

Assuming that i is an int, the selector doesn't return any value, and when I delete the `[id*=i]`, I get all the element where the `Id` finishes with `_value`.

So how can I get the values of elements that finishes with `_value` AND containes the integer `i` in it's `Id`?

Comment: use string concatenation - `$('input[id$="_value"][id*=' + i + '"]')`

Comment: Arun has answered your question, but your basic strategy appears to be flawed -- for instance, `$('input[id$="_value"][id*="1"]')` will match both id `1` and id `11` (or `12`, `13`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHamidi, I know I just wanted to simplify my question, actually I'm checking if my Id Contains "\_i\_" not just "i".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation to use the value of variable `i` - you are trying to find input elements with `id` ending with `_value` and has an `i` in its `id`

```
$('input[id$="_value"][id*="' + i + '"]')
```

But since you can get complete id, you can use the id selector also

```
$('#something_' + i + '_value')
```

Comment: because otherwise i will not be recognized as the internal variable i

Comment: @arun Can you add a fiddle?